# How to estimate the noise variation of each image block of a forged image using principal component analysis (pca)?

Tags: image-processing, pca, noise-reduction

From each image block of size 32*32, how to estimate the noise variation using principal component analysis?

To distinguish the forged section of the forged image, I converted the image into HSV first, extracted the saturation component, segmented the image into non-overlapping blocks of size 32*32, then from each block I need to estimate the noise variation using principal component analysis. How to do this? Python code for this will be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some reference to share that you are trying to use? Why did you extract Saturation specifically? Why do you believe you need PCA to assess noise?

Comment: I am trying to implement this from this paper as part of my research work: https://ijiset.com/vol2/v2s8/IJISET_V2_I8_48.pdf   Basically, I need to find out the noise variance of each image block, so, any help regarding this will be helpful.